# What does np.mean(data.isnull()) exactly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

in creating a cleaning project throught Python, I've found this code:

```
# let's see if there is any missing data

for col in df.columns:
    pct_missing = np.mean(df[col].isnull())
    print('{} - {}%'.format(col, round(pct_missing,2)))
```

Which actually works fine, giving back the % of null values per column in the dataframe, but I'm a little confused on how it works:

First we define a loop for each column in the dataframe, then we execute that mean but exactly the mean of what? The mean for each columns of the quantity of null cells or what?

Just for reference, I've worked around it with this:

```
NullValues=df.isnull().sum()/len(df)
print('{} - {}%'.format(col, round(NullValues,2)))
```

that gives me back basically the same results but just to understand the mechanism...I'm confused about the first block of code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's something that's very intuitive once you're used to it.  The steps leading to this kind of code could be like the following:

1. To get the percentage of null values, we need to count all null rows, and divide the count by the total number of rows.
2. So, first we need to detect the null rows.  This is easy, as there is a provided method: `df[col].isnull()`.
3. The result of `df[col].isnull()` is a new column consisting of booleans -- `True` or `False`.
4. Now we need to count the `True`s.  Here we can realize that counting `True`s in a boolean array is the same as summing the array: `True` can be converted to 1, and `False` to zero.
5. So we would be left with `df[col].isnull().sum() / len(df[col])`.
6. But summing and dividing by the length is just the arithmetic mean!   Therefore, we can shorten this to arrive at the final result: `mean(df[col].isnull())`.

Answer (score 1):

`df[col].isnull()` is  assigning a boolean (`True`/`False`) depending on the NA/null state of the values.

`np.mean` computes the average of the values, with `True` as `1` and `False` as `0`, which is a equivalent of computing the proportion of Null values in the column.

```
np.mean([True, False, False, False])

# equivalent to 
np.mean([1, 0, 0, 0])

# 0.25
```

Answer (score 0):

the first thing that happens is the

```
df[col].isnull()
```

this creates a list of bool values with True beeing when the column is null so if for example the values are [x1, x2, x3, null, x4] then it gives the vector [False, False, False, True, False].

The next step is then the np.mean funcion. This function calculates the mean value of the vector but replaces True with 1 and False with 0. This gives the vector [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

The mean of this vector is equal to the sum of nulls divided by the length of the vector which is the method you are using.

Just a comment. It does not give a percent you need to multiply by 100.